# Possible to get username for owner of mentioned comment?

Tags: instagram-graph-api, facebook-webhooks, bubble.io

I'm brand new to wrangling the IG Graph (and to API's, in general) and hoping someone might be willing to lend a hand. A bit of context: I am building a SaaS on Bubble.io. I have my authentication set up and am in the process of developing my FB App. In short, I want to enable the following:

- Auth'd users curate content on IG by @mentioning my app's account in a comment to a post.
- Those comments are intercepted via web hook (currently running smoothly on Integromat).
- They payload is then passed to an API Workflow on Bubble, which parses the comment ID
- The workflow then retrieves details of the comment and associated post.
- The comment is correlated with the appropriate app user based on the username of the comment's owner.

The final two steps is where I'm confused. Based on my reading of FB's documentation, it seems impossible to retrieve a username or user id for the owner of a mentioned comment, which clearly presents a problem for me. Is this the case or am I just missing something? It seems to me there should be a way of getting at this data.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vDwf.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `username` field, as done followingly:

```
mentioned_comment.comment_id(COMMENT_ID){media,text,username}
```